# Rails - where to put a css file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I put my css file into public/stylesheets directory (by the way, there was no stylesheets directory by default). From the layout in app/views I render it by

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %>`

When I view the page css doesn't appear to work(no changes comparing with clean html), in the html code I see this one:

```
<link href="/assets/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I don't understand why are assets here instead of stylesheets and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 3.1, right? If so, you'd want to put your stylesheet in `app/assets/stylesheets/main.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a file at `/assets/main.css`? Use that instead, or replace it.

What version of rails are you using? Rails3? Are you following a Rails2 tutorial by chance?

Comment: I use rails3 and even in rails tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html it's said that the directory should be /public/stylesheets.

Comment: I think that tutorial is slightly out of date, if you're using the very latest Rails 3.1 (per mu's answer).